# Issues with google data studio displaying different data values at different times (BigQuery+Data Studio)

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I created a dashboard in Data Studio that is using a table in BigQuery of about 7.6GB in size. Some of the graphs are meant to show change in minutes (in the data, I have minute 00,20 and 40 of every hour). However, the graphs some days show different data points without me doing any changes at all to the table or the dashboard. For instance, this is how the graph looked in February 14, 15 and 16.

Feb 14
[image]
Feb 15
[image]
Feb 16
[image]

I've noticed that when this happens, the graph is randomly showing a value for a data point that is not even in the raw data. For instance, it shows that on Jan 31 at 3:50ish the graph went down to ~1K, but I checked the raw data and as expected, there we don't have any data points at all outside of minutes 00, 20 and 40.

This makes me think that it's an issue in the aggregation and maybe the format of my date and time field, but it still doesn't make sense to me why sometimes it works fine and sometimes it does not. (eg format. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM)

Any suggestions of what I should try to prevent this from happening? Would really appreciate any suggestions at this point

Comment: Noticed something else: when the graph is NOT "Not accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine" it doesn't work well, but when it is it seems to work without a problem. However, I haven't set up anything for BQ BI Engine so I'm not sure how it's even using it sometimes.

Comment: What is the schema of your DateTime? Is it Timestamp, DateTime? Is it being parsed from a string? Are you truncating the Timestamp? Are you using any CURRENT_DATETIME() functions? Is this a time series  visualization?

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was happening, but I am not sure I know all the details: The amount I was including was too big and for some reason, graphs were sometimes being powered by BigQuery BI Engine (even though I've never set it up). Whenever it was not powered by BigQuery BI Engine, graphs would not work as expected (eg. Feb. 15th graph above). Therefore, I lowered the amount of my data by lowering the frequency of it from every 10 minutes to every hour and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Ah, that sounds terrible.. Please feel free to file a bug if you notice something like this again. It is expected to see BI Engine when you use DataStudio, because there is 1Gb free quota for DataStudio dashboards. But when BI Engine is not used, result should still be the same.